# Connect Sage Intacct data with ELK for visualisation/Dashboard

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud, intacct

I would like to connect my ELK setup (which is on Elastic Cloud) with the data stored in Sage Intacct.
What is the correct way to get the data from Sage Intacct and use it to visualise in Kibana?
Main problem is how we connect the data source or what is the process for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a sage intacct integration sample. It is built in Linx, a low-code dev platform for backends. You can use it to extract your data and load into a dashboard of your choice using a REST API.

Github sample: https://github.com/linx-software/Sage_Intacct_Linx_Sample
blog: https://linx.software/blog/sage-intacct-integration/